# Use Facebook Graph API to post a photo to a user's timeline with an @ tag

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags

I am building an app where users can post a photo directly to their timeline from our app. We want to pre-populate it with some branded text and a link to the brand's Facebook page. For example, something like: "Check out my photo at XYZ event". And XYZ would be a link to http://facebook.com/xyz

The closest thing I can find is this: http://digitizor.com/2011/01/24/tag-user-facebook-graph/ but it would seem that this trick is no longer working.

We are using CURL to upload the photo to the users wall with the following array converted to a string for the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS:

```
$graph_url= "https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?"
. "access_token=" .$access_token;
$fields = array(
'url'=>"http://" . $imgPath,
'message'=>urlencode(stripslashes($_POST['message'] . " @[$brandFBUID:1:$brandName]" )) );
```